# WPF Datagrid Inside WrapPanel?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro, wrappanel

I have a lot of columns in my DataGrid and would like to be able to put it into a wrap panel so it has the ability to resize while still displaying all of it's contents. Here's a visual example:

**No WrapPanel**

[image]

**With WrapPanel (This is just two DataGrids for representation)**

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't get the DataGrid to wrap like you want it to.

To achieve the effect that you want would require creating a custom control.